# What kind of plane could be leased back to a flight school?

Tags: aerobatics, flight-school

I was having a brief chat with the CFI at a local club/school and he talked about lease back, assuming that the maintenance and insurance is paidfor by the lease back and isnt an issue the question is this, what sort of aircraft can I buy to lease back, is there restrictions on the age or hours on a hire aircraft or can any 2 seater do the job, I am getting back into flying after a long break and want to get back into aerobatics, so something like a 150/152 aerobat would be ideal, there are no aerobatic planes in my local area so there is an incentive on both sides to do this ?

Comment: If it is in the US, it must be of US registry. The only requirement is it must be a ***certificated aircraft***, no experimental or home builts. The only other requirement is it must have an annual and 100hr inspections until the next annual. So long as the airplane meets the maintenance inspections, their are no other restrictions.

Comment: If it sounds to good to be true...

Comment: The owner or manager of the school can probably tell you what type(s) of aircraft they’d be interested in leasing back from you. Maybe keeping the fleet common is a goal, or adding a taildragger is under consideration, or adding something with particular avionics, or preferring particular avionics, or ...

Comment: You need to talk to somebody who is doing a leaseback with the flight school to see what they are experiencing. Leaseback contracts can vary quite a bit. You also need to talk to your insurance company because your insurance rates may go up quite a bit. Leasebacks can help defer some costs, but they have drawbacks (you have to work around the aircraft's schedule, students banging up the airplane, etc).

Comment: See: [AOPA Aircraft Owners Guide to Aircraft Leasing (Leasebacks)](https://www.aopa.org/training-and-safety/pic-archive/aircraft-ownership/aircraft-owners-guide-to-aircraft-leasing)

Comment: I'm not entirely sure what you're asking here. You could leaseback any aircraft, if the contract is acceptable to both the school and the owner. I may be wrong, but it sounds like you're asking if leasebacks are a good idea or not, and that's a highly subjective question that we can't easily answer here: a lot depends on your personal situation, the contract terms, the insurance implications etc.

Comment: It's for the UK, was just thinking out loud, but there's a massive difference between, for example a Robin 2112 @ £20k and a Pitts S2 at £50k, just browsing ads and seeing what interests me at the moment, trying to make it all work out :)

Comment: The ONLY reason to do a leaseback is if you've run all the numbers and are planning to do it as a business, and you can afford to take a loss. Do NOT do it if you think you will reduce the cost of flying -- in the vast majority of cases leasebacks are a subsidy to the club. If you want to get into aerobatics -- great! Rent an aerobatic airplane!

Comment: BTW in the US a leaseback is not an operation "for hire or compensation" unless the club provides everything -- airplane, instructor, fuel, etc. In the usual scenario where CFIs are independent contractors, it's not a "for hire" operation and no 100-hour is required; and the airplane does not have to be certificated.